# css scale background to a certain ratio of image

Tags: css, background, scaling

Is there a CSS3 method of scaling the background image of an element by certain ratio of that image's dimensions?

All of the documentation I find when searching suggests 'background-size', but when a percentage is given there, it is a percentage of the element to which that background belongs.  I want to scale relative to the size of the background image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one you need ? Try this link https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/dtxLjmdv/. I just added `padding` with percentage value top and bottom, no `height` required. And uses `background-size:cover`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I need though.  I'm actually looking for the background to remain a particular scale regardless of the element's size.  With that one, it scales with the size of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you?

https://jsfiddle.net/oo3yxvo0/

Instead of adding percentage, try to add cover to the `background-size`

Comment: This still seems to have the same problem I'm trying to avoid though.  When I resize the window, the background scales with it.

Comment: If you want the picture to be static, then you should add pixel values to the background-size. Though, that will not be responsive

Comment: Yeah, in the end I think I'll be using a combination of that and javascript to get what I need.